# How do i move the xammp folder on my macbook to desktop?

Tags: apache, xampp, htdocs

i got a macbook and installed xampp on it, but i find it very difficult to locate the xampp htdocs folder. is there a way i can move the folder to desktop?

Thanks

i try moving with terminal, moving manually too. doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could create a desktop shortcut to the htdocs file, this would allow you to easily click on it and open the file without searching through xaamp's program files.

Moving the entire file wouldn't work as xampp looks for htdocs in its default directory, so moving it would break the system, unless you managed to get xampp to search for htdocs on the desktop, but that could be tricky

To make it a desktop shortcut, read [this](https://www.lifewire.com/create-desktop-shortcuts-on-a-mac-5184827) for help